# Java button not working

Tags: java, button, action, applet

The button is firing the event, but it is not showing. It creates new circles, but it doesn't draw the new circles. Is there something I'm not doing? (first java applet). It's probably something stupid I'm missing..

```
import java.applet.*;


    public class CircleApp extends Applet {

        public circle[] circles;
        public Button regen;

        public CircleApp(){
        }

        public void init()
        {
            this.setSize(400, 400);
            genCircles(getWidth(), getHeight());
            regen = new Button("New Circles");
            add(regen);
        }

        public boolean action(Event e, Object args)
        {
            genCircles(getWidth(), getHeight());
            return true;
        }

        public void genCircles(int wid, int hei)
        {
            circles = new circle[20];
            Random gen = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                int x = gen.nextInt(wid);
                int y = gen.nextInt(hei);
                int rx = Math.min(x, wid - x);
                int ry = Math.min(y, hei - y);
                int r = Math.min(rx, ry);

                circles[i] = new circle(new Point(x, y), gen.nextInt(r));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i; j < 20; j++)
                {
                    if (circles[i].intersects(circles[j]))
                    {
                        circles[i].intersects = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                g.setColor((circles[i].intersects) ? Color.blue : Color.magenta);
                g.drawOval(circles[i].location.x,
                        circles[i].location.y,
                        circles[i].radius,
                        circles[i].radius);
            }
        }
    }

import java.awt.Point;


public class circle {
    public Point location;
    public int radius;
    public boolean intersects;

    public circle(Point h, int radius)
    {
        this.location = h;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public circle()
    {
        this(new Point(0, 0), 1);
    }
    public boolean intersects(circle other)
    {
        return (this.location.distance(other.location) <
                (double)(this.radius + other.radius));
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`repaint()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) to redraw the new circles after you generate them.

Also, not directly related to your question, but [`action()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#action%28java.awt.Event,%20java.lang.Object%29) is deprecated -- use an [action listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) on the button instead.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see where you've adding an ActionListener to your button, and without this, the Button will not be able to associate its press with any code action.  Perhaps I'm missing something though... please tell me what is supposed to happen when a button is pressed, and what code calls this for you?

I suggest if possible that you not code in AWT but rather code with Swing which is much more robust and flexible.  Also there are more tutorials available for it and more expertise in it here and on other sites compared to AWT.

Comment: +1, for suggesting using Swing. The painting techniques are different between AWT and Swing and the posters time will be better spent learning the Swing techniques.